# Spring Boot Websocket STOMP Crud

Tags: javascript, react.js, spring, websocket

I have a personal project that runs the backend under spring boot that implements websocket for real-time functionality and I apply it to a crud operations.

Although the code is working and work as expected I doubt if I do the correct implementation of spring websocket here.

I've used React as my frontend as call the crud function on their `@MessageMapping` annotation.

The way I implement the backend to my frontend is.

- Fetching all `Person` records and store in an array state.
- Then for create `Person` record I just append in to the new record to the persons state array

I doubt if I do it correctly because when I debug the websocket client, I found out that it.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@Autowired
public PersonController(PersonRepository personRepository) {
    this.personRepository = personRepository;
}

@MessageMapping("/person/add")
public void createPerson(Person person) {
    Person savePerson = new Person(person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName());
    personRepository.save(savePerson);
    this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/person", viewPersons());
}


@RequestMapping("/person")
@ResponseBody
public List<Person> viewPersons(){
    List<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll();
    return persons;
}

@MessageMapping("/person/delete")
public void deletePerson(@Payload PersonDeleteRequest request) {
    Person person = personRepository.findById(request.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No id found."));
    personRepository.delete(person);
    this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/person", viewPersons());
}

@MessageMapping("/person/update")
public void updatePerson(@Payload Person requestPerson) {
    Person person = personRepository.findById(requestPerson.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No id found."));
    person.setFirstName(requestPerson.getFirstName());
    person.setLastName(requestPerson.getLastName());
    personRepository.save(person);
    this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/person", viewPersons());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Autowired` is not required on constructor in Spring over 4.3 (class has to be annotated as bean and have only one constructor).

Inject `SimpMessagingTemplate template` in a constructor. Now you mix annotation and constructor injection.

IMHO you shouldn't put any business login in controller methods. I would move it all to separate service. For example I would write `updatePerson()` like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/person/update")
public void updatePerson(@Payload Person requestPerson) {
    personService.updatePerson(requestPerson);
    this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/person", personService.viewPersons());
}
```

In `updatePerson()` and `createPerson()` you should have separate objects instead of Person class. E.g. `CreatePersonRequest` and `UpdatePersonRequest`

I would change `viewPersons()` to `getAllPersons()`

The rest look fine :)